# (Linear)Layout - How to get the number of elements?

Tags: android, android-layout

Can I somehow extract the number out of a `Layout`?

I have code similar to this:

```
linearLayout.addView(randomView, 3);
```

This means, the element `randomView` is inserted at position 3 (so it is the 4. element).
I removed another element inside the `linearLayout` and because of the hardcoded number `3` I ran into an Exception. I want to add my `randomView` to the end of the layout, so it would be nice if I could do something like this:

```
linearLayout.addView(randomView, linearLayout.size());
```

Even if I'm changing the elements of a **specific layout**, the `randomView` would then always be at the end of all other elements.

Comment: then don't specify `3`. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View%29

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify the position view will be added at the end of the ViewGroup.

```
linearLayout.addView(randomView);
```

But if you need to specify the position you can get the child count and do this

```
int childCount = ((ViewGroup)linearLayout).getChildCount();
linearLayout.addView(randomView, childCount);
```

If you need to access the view inside your linear layout then you can do this

```
View childView = ((ViewGroup)linearLayout).getChildAt(position);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why just not do:

```
linearLayout.addView(randomView);
```

I remember it adds the view to end of the viewgroup.

Comment: Thanks. It had to be that simple. :)